# I don't understand why the j variable is assigned twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, computational-geometry

Quick question. I'm relatively new to C# and have a quick question about the follow code. Why is j set equal to one value and then set equal to another almost immediately?

**Poly.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class Poly    
{    
    public static bool ContainsPoint (Vector2[] polyPoints, Vector2 p)    
    {    
        var j = polyPoints.Length - 1;    
        var inside = false;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < polyPoints.Length; j = i++)    
        {    
            var pi = polyPoints[i];    
            var pj = polyPoints[j];
    
            if (((pi.y <= p.y && p.y < pj.y) || (pj.y <= p.y && p.y < pi.y)) && (p.x < (pj.x - pi.x) * (p.y - pi.y) / (pj.y - pi.y) + pi.x))    
                inside = !inside;    
        }
    
        return inside;    
    } 
}
```

Comment: ```j``` is remembering the previous ```i``` value for each iteration.  But you need to manually set the initial 'previous' value for the first iteration.

Comment: Oh, I should add that the ```j = i++``` happens *after* the first iteration.  It looks like it's immediate due to its position in the code, but the execution happens last.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code.

Answer (score 1):

A [`for(initializer; condition; iterator)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) loop works as follows:

- `initializer` is executed first and only **once**. It is usually used to declare the iteration variable (s) and define an init state
- `condition` is an expression returning a `bool` and is checked **before** each iteration. Only if it is `true` the code inside the loop is executed and the next iteration checked etc
- `iterator` is executed **after** each iteration. Usually used to increase/alternate the iteration variable or whatever is finally needed to break the loop (not necessarily though)

Your `j` is not re-assigned immediately but after each iteration .. and also not twice but possibly a lot of times ;)

---

So here it looks like it is used to create a complete closed loop through the `polyPoints`.

`j` is used to store the index of the **previous** entry in `polyPoint`.

Since for the very first iteration there is no "previous" one you instead use the very last point (`polyPoints.Length - 1`).

Then **after** each iteration you basically do in one single line

```
j = i;
i+=1;
```

Explanation: The **postfix** [increment-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#increment-operator-) `i++` **first** returns the **current** `i`, only then it increments `i`. (In contrary to `++i` which first increments, then returns the already incremented `i`)

So you store the current `i` before moving to the next iteration. Thus, inside the loop you always check the current (`pi`) against the previous (`pj`) entry in `polyPoints`, using the very last point for the first iteration. -> Closed cycle

---

You could and in my opinion **should** just write it as

```
var j = polyPoints.Length - 1;
var inside = false;

for (int i = 0; i < polyPoints.Length; i++)
{
    var pi = polyPoints[i];
    var pj = polyPoints[j];

    if (((pi.y <= p.y && p.y < pj.y) || (pj.y <= p.y && p.y < pi.y)) && (p.x < (pj.x - pi.x) * (p.y - pi.y) / (pj.y - pi.y) + pi.x))
    {
        inside = !inside;
    }

    // Do it here! This is way easier to understand
    j = i;
}
```

Which is way easier to understand for you and other readers. Seems to me like your current code is the result of someone trying to over-"optimize" too much at the cost of readability

Comment: After pondering, I prefer the version in the OP. Because the third expression in a for loop expresses "routine" work to get from one element to the next. Here we are moving from an edge to the next and both `i` and `j` are involved. Those dealing with polygons are familiar with this process. I use to write `...; j= i, i++)`. In cases with three vertices involved, I would generalize to `k= j, j= i, i++)`.

Answer (score 1):

"almost immediately": no, it is reassigned only at the end of the for loop.

This construct ensures that `j, i` covers all edges of a closed polygon.